# Should I use a persitant Linux live or install ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, persistence

Good evening!

I'm learning unix and I have my last project on it which is doing a shell. I want to work on this project at home and I'm wondering if I should use a persitant Linux live or install ubuntu with an unpersitant Lili?

I'm okay having definitly Ubuntu on my hard drive, I'm use to it from my university, but is that necessary?
What would you advise me?

Comment: You could install virtualbox and use Ubuntu as virtual machine, then  delete it once you're done

Answer (score 0):

First, is your home laptop already running Windows? If yes, and if you want to keep Windows, you'll need to set it up on dual boot, which with UEFI might be tricky for a beginner.

For your project, a Live Linux USB stick might be sufficient.  The advantage is that you won't have to worry with installations and fear of data loss (again, assuming your laptop runs Windows).  Just remember to do regular backups on another disk...

Another option would be to install VMware and then create an Ubuntu VM on it.  In this way you'll be free to experiment whatever you want.